# Is there any way to put CSS link in XML file dynamically generated by php?

Tags: php, xml

I have successfully generated an xml file using dom in php dynamically, but I am unsure how to put CSS link in it.

I need the php code to link CSS with that automatically generated XML file.

Comment: what you've done so far? and be more clear

Comment: I have generated xml file using php DOM parser. I didn't find any instruction for linking CSS. So, I am here.

Comment: I clearly mentioned it about how to use DOM parser to generate a line to link CSS in my XML file. I asked it here because I couldn't find it anywhere else. @ThW has already provided the answer. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link an CSS in XML you can use the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction. Use the corresponding method on DOMDocument to create it and then append/insert it just like any other node.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild(
  $document->createProcessingInstruction(
    'xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/css" href="styles.css"'
  )
);
$document->appendChild(
  $document->createElement('example')
);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles.css"?> 
<example/>
```